# From a given Item in a Sharepoint List, create subitems based on multiple choice column

Tags: splistitem, sharepoint-list

I would like to create a tracker of projects in Sharepoint. 
This is for translation projects where each project would need to be translated into 10-30 different languages. I have a list where I can add a project as a individual item, but is it possible to create a subitem per language where I can add the status and comments for each language? Is this even possible in Sharepoint?. Is there any  tool other than a list for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create language list - this will be the master list of languages. 
   2 .Create project list - this is already created by you.
2. Create sub project list - with lookup columns to language list and project list.
3. After you create entry in project list, you can create multiple entries in Sub Project list and track the data.

Do you want to create the sub project list items automatically  or manually? Above approach requires list item to be created manually.

Comment: Monica, Thank you so much for your help. This was really helpful!. In case I would like to automate the creation of the items in the sublist, this would need some Javascript development, am I right?

Comment: Javascript is one of the options, you can also have sharepoint designer wokflow to do it.

Comment: Great. Thank Monica. I will try to do this in Sharepoint Flow!

Comment: Yes, flow should also do the work. Let know if you need help !!!